# Is it possible to use ternary operator for console.log?

Tags: reactjs

I thought this would be something simple to do, but I don't think it's possible, why is that?

This is what I'm trying to do.

```
console.log("hello") ? bool : "";
```

This gives me an error: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression. Not sure exactly what that means.

Comment: Can you explain your goal? What are you trying to do? There might be a better solution.

Comment: What is the point of this code? What are you ultimately trying to achieve? `console.log` **always** returns undefined so it doesn't make sense to use it in a ternary like this.

Comment: Please explain your exact intended logic.

Comment: The intended logic is to console.log "hello" if the bool is true, and do nothing if the bool is false.

Comment: see: [Short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#short-circuit_evaluation) `bool && console.log('hello')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you want to "conditionally" `console.log` via the tenery operator.

It is possible to conditionally (via ternary) change the output of `console.log()` based on a bool like so:

```
console.log(bool ? "hello" : "")
```

In this case though, it *will* output an empty string to the console.

My guess is that you only want to log if the bool is true. It's quite trivial to add a quick if statement:

```
if (bool) console.log('hello')
```

Via Ternary, if you ultimately wish to do this, you'd need to do something like the following:

```
bool ? console.log("test") : null;
```

In my opinion, this looks less cleaner than a simple bool statement as you'd need to provide some value (Simplest probably being null or 0) which is then assigned to nothing.

Comment: Thank you, I was debugging stuff and felt that using a ternary operand was faster.

Comment: @Muath Number one rule I've learned in programming: Do prematurely optimize anything. In the end, you'll be only saving nanoseconds, which in the end is simply not worth even thinking about.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. you have to evaluate the expression at runtime.
Do I like this.

```
const someBool = true;
console.log(someBool?'hello':'goodbye');
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `==` or `===`?

Comment: Yes this is what I'm looking for actually, I didn't know I can use the ternary operator inside the log. This will save me some time. Thank you.